# Lazy One-to-one Optional Bidirectional Mapping using Hibernate annotations

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to create a Lazy One-to-one Bidirectional 'Optional' Mapping using Hibernate annotations. I know that the normal usage of `@MappedBy` and `@JoinColumn` result in N+1 queries being fired every time.

Is there a way I can avoid this? Not just at runtime, but at the `POJO` level. I am using `Hibernate 4.3`, so can't think about bytecode enhancement.

Further, if there is no way out, is it possible to apply criteria on unidirectional mappings. For example, I have `A <-> B,` and `C -> A` as mappings. And I am searching on `B`. Is it possible to apply a restriction on `C` when `C` is clearly unidirectional with `A`?

Answer (score 0):

The `@OneToOne` annotaion doesn't work in hibernate as needed. Please consider the `@LazyToOne` or try using `@OneToMany` like `@OneToOne`. Also you can attempt `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`.

p.s. The `@LazyToOne` annotation doesn't exist in JPA realization, you should use `@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)` there

Comment: @LazyToOne will not work for me since my parent association is optional. Reference: http://agori.github.io/one_to_one_optional.html

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a complete but minimal examples of **LAZY bidirectional @OneToOne**, so here it is. It is neither hibernate-version-dependent nor does it misuse `@OneToMany`.

**Parent**

Defines the `id` and is responsible for managing the consistency/synchronization, but technically does not own the relationship, because it can not reference any unique index in `B` (or at least we do not want to add redundant data).

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(
            mappedBy = "a",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    private B b;

    public void setB(B b) {
        if (b == null) {
            if (this.b != null) {
                this.b.setA(null);
            }
        } else {
            b.setA(this);
        }
        this.b = b;
    }
    // ... other setters/getters
}
```

**Child**

Technically owns the relationship by re-using the id of parent `A`.

```
@Entity
public class B {
    @Id
    // Not generated but shared with A
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "id") // otherwise use "a_id" instead of "id" in the DB column
    private A a;
    // ... other setters/getters
}
```

And this is how the tables should look like (assuming postgres):

```
CREATE TABLE a (
    id bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
);

CREATE TABLE b (
    id bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES a(id);
);
```